# What's the meaning of "laugh men out of their follies"?

Tags: meaning

"laugh men out of their follies" What does this phrase mean?

Answer (score 2):

This expression comes from Jonathan Swift and is not current usage, however it describes laughing your troubles/cares away.  Laughter is something to ease the daily troubles of life.

Here, it implies that humour is best when it's laughing with, rather than laughing at, others—without being mean and nasty and putting others down.

> By what disposition of the mind, what influence of the stars, or what
>   situation of the climate, this endowment is bestowed upon mankind, may
>   be a question fit for philosophers to discuss. It is certainly the
>   best ingredient toward that kind of satire, which is most useful, and
>   gives the least offence; which, instead of lashing, laughs men out of
>   their follies and vices; and is the character that gives Horace the
>   preference to Juvenal.

Hope this makes sense to you too!

Comment: Visser labels verbs pressed into transitive service as 'quasi-transitive'. 'She laughed her troubles away' is an example using 'laugh' transitively that I'm sure I've come across, and 'laugh your cares away' is quite common (+1 for the link), but 'laugh men out of their follies and vices' (with a sentient being as DO) doesn't seem to have caught on.

Comment: It means something quite different to me.  I take it to mean to cause people through laughing at foolish or vicious behaviour to stop behaving in those ways.  Consider, for example, in Gulliver's Travels there is a religious war over whether one should crack open the big or little end of a boiled egg.  It's patently ridiculous and laughable and may cause some people to be less militant about different interpretations of religious texts.

Comment: @Al Maki I think that 'laughing at the ridiculous things we as mankind do' and 'laughing alongside others, seeing the behaviours rather than the other guy as ridiculous' are totally compatible. And healthy / wellbeing-producing.